# XSD Nested elements of the same name with different child elements

Tags: xml, xsd, complextype

I am currently re writing an XSD to be more specific when accepting data. There is a complexType to accept all elements with name "part" containing an attribute "partname", without validating any child nodes within the part. Here is the current complexType XSD code:

```
<xs:complexType name="partType" mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="partname" type="stringtype" use="required" />
</xs:complexType>
```

And here is a sample of the types of "parts" I receive in XML:

```
<part partname="customer">
    <seq>1</seq>
    <type>owner</type>
    <part partname="conviction">
        <convictionCode>12345</convictionCode>
        <convictionDate>2011-06-02</convictionDate>
        <fine />
        <term />
        <type />
        <age>22</age>
        <suspension>0</suspension>
    </part>
    <part partname="claim">
        <dateOfLoss>2010-05-05</dateOfLoss>
        <claimType>Accident</claimType>
        <claimCost />
        <claimFault>No</claimFault>
        <type>owner</type>
    </part>
</part>
```

I have had trouble finding information on how to achieve content validation when the same element comes in multiple forms and can nest within each other.

Any recommendations of what syntax may be appropriate are appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You write

> I have had trouble finding information on how to achieve content validation when the same element comes in multiple forms and can nest within each other.

In general, when parent elements can have children (or more generally descendants) which have the same name as the parent, one of two situations applies:

1. The parent and child elements have the same type, which is structurally recursive.

   In this case the key requirement is to ensure that the recursion can terminate, by making sure the occurrence of like-named children is optional.  It is also crucial here to make either the element or its type, or both, be a top-level schema component.

   E.g.

   ```
   <element name="e" type="e"/>
   <complexType name="e">
     <sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
       <element ref="e"/>
     </
   </
   ```
2. The parent and child elements have different types.

   Here the key technical mechanism to use is locality; in the most common case, the outer or parent element will be a top-level element, and the inner or child element will be local to the outer element's type.

   E.g.

   ```
   <element name="e" type="e"/>
   <complexType name="e">
     <sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
       <element name="e" type="nested-e"/>
     </
   </
   <complexType name="nested-e">
     <sequence>
       <element ref="a"/>
       <element ref="b"/>  
       <element ref="c"/>
     </
   </
   ```

This does not address the variation in structure you show among the child elements named 'part'; if you cannot get the vocabulary redesigned to give different names to elements of different types and ancestry, you will need to look for an XSD 1.1 solution using conditional type assignment and/or assertions.

Answer (score 0):

The XSD will validate your XML, but won't check the nested `part` elements; nested part elements will fall under the unchecked realm of `xs:any`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="part" type="partType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="partType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="partname" use="required" />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

You could stop here and use the above XSD, but to tighten it up a bit and have the nested `part` elements also checked, you might think that you could use this XSD instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="part" type="partType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="partType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax" />
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="part" type="partType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="partname" use="required" />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

The problem, though, is that the above XSD violates the [Unique Particle Attribution](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cos-nonambig) rule because of the ambiguity as to whether a `part` element should be validated per the `xs:any` or the `xs:element/@name="part"`.

**If you can make a structural change to your XML** to have a fixed `parts` containing element *ahead* of your varying elements, you can skirt the Unique Particle Attribution rule and still have **both your recursive structure and the variable element content** allowed by `xs:any`:

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<part partname="customer">
    <parts>
      <part partname="conviction">
        <parts/>
        <convictionCode>12345</convictionCode>
        <convictionDate>2011-06-02</convictionDate>
        <fine />
        <term />
        <type />
        <age>22</age>
        <suspension>0</suspension>
      </part>
      <part partname="claim">
        <parts/>
        <dateOfLoss>2010-05-05</dateOfLoss>
        <claimType>Accident</claimType>
        <claimCost />
        <claimFault>No</claimFault>
        <type>owner</type>
      </part>
    </parts>
    <seq>1</seq>
    <type>owner</type>
</part>
```

### XSD

This XSD will validate the above XML successfully:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="part" type="partType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="partType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="parts">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" 
                        name="part" type="partType"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:any maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="partname" use="required" />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: hi kjhughes, thank you for your input.  unfortunately changing the XML structure is out of scope as we already receive this XML from multiple third parties as well as our internal systems. I would agree changing the structure is the way to go if this was not the case. Thanks again!